# Linux error for array in php: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, linux, http-status-code-503

This line of code causes an error on Linux.

```
$p_event_a = strtotime($p_events['date_time'][$evn]);
```

The error goes away if I comment out the for loop.  Why should an array cause a 503 error?

```
    $p_events = array();

// Retrieve Public Events
    for ( $ev = 0 ; $ev < $nev ; $ev++ ) {
        $p_event_r = strtotime($ev_order[$ev]);
        for ( $evn = 0 ; $evn < $nev ; $evn++ ) {
            $p_event_a = strtotime($p_events['date_time'][$evn]);
            if ( $p_event_a == $p_event_r ) {
                $evnt_date = date('Y-m-d H:i', $p_event_a);
                if ( $evnt_date <= $endd && $evnt_date >= $stad ) {
                    $public_event = '<span> <a>'.$p_events['title'][$evn].'</a> </span>';           
                    $event['tit'] = $public_event;
                    $event['cat'] = $aevent[0];
                    $event['cnm'] = $aevent[1];
                    $event['seq'] = $aevent[2];             
                    $event['col'] = $aevent[5];
                    $event['bco'] = $aevent[6];
                    $event['inf'] = '';
                    $evtList[$evnt_date][] = $event;        
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you exhausted your error logs for clues? Typically speaking this is a response code that is the result of a CDN that serves your data being unable to get a repsonse back from the server when you're in a strictly PHP environment, as the other errors that throw this are due to memory but will generally give you a "Fatal error: Allowed memory XXXXXX exhausted". In any event, you should place `memory_get_usage` in your iterator to see if you hit a ceiling and if so you have your answer.

Comment: As Damien was saying the script might be stuck in the loop.  I am looking that that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a totally wild guess, mind everyone.

First, you need to enable error reporting to "see" the error on the screen:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

otherwise, you need to go check your error logs to see what happened.

My guess? You've encountered an "index out of bound" error because you're trying to access an array index which doesn't exist. ( count the elements of           `$p_events['date_time'][$evn]` and see if they are the number you think they should)

Where does `$nev` comes from? Is it from a `count()` call?

If your `for` loop is equivalent to:

```
for ( $evn = 0 ; $evn < count($whatever) ; $evn++ ) {
```

be careful that `count()` returns the number of elements, but in your loop you start counting from 0, so you will be looping over an extra result. (ex, if count = 5, you have: 0 1 2 3 4 5, which is **6** elements).

Will this solve it?

```
for ( $evn = 0 ; $evn < ($nev-1) ; $evn++ ) {
```

(parenthesis aren't necessary in $nev-1, but it's for clarity purpose)

Comment: Thanks. There are a few things I could look at from your suggestions.  Yes, $nev comes from a count() call. For an array like this one, should count add the two dimensions? I have four elements in the first dimension and 301 in the second.